# ANDROID : adding call function when a button clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, call

I have added a ListView inside a fragment, when clicking that listview i see single itemview. when i click the button in that single item view a call should go to that particular id in the listview. button is for call , when its clicked and automatic cal should go . my code is down , phone numbers are stored in side parse server.  if anyone knows please help

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56) ;
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String phno="telephone";

            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(phno));
            startActivity(i);
        }
});
```

xml code

```
   <Button
            android:id="@+id/button56"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="TELE PHONE"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#EFEFEF"/>
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: call not going when i click the button in simulator  @Prerak Sola

Comment: Do you have permission in manifest for making calls? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: try using `Uri.parse("tel:" +number)` and I assume you have permission `.CALL_PHONE` in your manifest.

Comment: @Pradumn Kumar Mahanta    thanks working

Comment: @KuKeC thanks working

Comment: @Pradumn Kumar Mahanta put your answer in answer i'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using,

```
Uri.parse("tel:" +number)
```

and I assume you have added the permission,

`.CALL_PHONE`

in your manifest.

Comment: hi , can you give your mail id please @Pradumn Kumar Mahanta

Comment: @FaizalMohamed Would not mind that, but I think sharing it on a public domain like this would not be a good idea.

Comment: please check    @Pradumn Kumar Mahanta   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482688/calling-a-mail-client-when-clicking-a-button/42482740?noredirect=1#comment72106447_42482740

Answer (score 1):

Add to your manifest permission to make calls

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```