# Calling a mail client when clicking a button

Tags: android, android-intent, email-client

I have a ListView connected to parse server data is coming through parse. when I click  single item of the ListView it goes to single item view. there i have a button for email , what i need is when I click that email button and email client should open .with that particular single items email id . email id's are stored in a column in parse database . any one knows please tel how to do this ?

**my database is parse server , I need to get emails dynamically from a
parse column. each singe item has a different email  ... email column
name is "email"**

*

> I used an answer below and edited like this but no receiver email showing

*

---

### edited code using below answer directing to mail client , but no receiver email showing

```
btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String phnoo = object.getString("email");


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                   intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"+phnoo));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

---

> my java code for calling  email client

```
  btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5) ;
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phno="email";

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:" +phno);
                intent.setData(data);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

> xml code  for button

```
   <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="E-MAIL"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#EFEFEF"/>
```

Comment: do you want share text via mail? if yes, you can use `Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

Comment: I want to open a email client when people click the email button  ..

Comment: @Nazim ch only email showing null in mail client . can you tell why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would help you

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
in.setType("plain/text");
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "mail id" });
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(in, ""));
```

Comment: please check my code  i edted  its always coming same email can you tel why

Comment: from where do you get the mail id to be send?

Comment: I'm getting it form a parse server database . the column name is "email"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481317/android-adding-call-function-when-a-button-clicked     please check this list i'm getting the phone numbers here similarly i need email ids in this     @Nazim ch

Comment: please check the link

Comment: make sure that the parsing value is a string and also fetching it into adnroid activity is in a perfect manner

Comment: please check my edited code is top .. when I pull another string column its working but when i pull email cloumn its showing null  please check top code is the code  @Nazim ch

Comment: hi @Nazim ch   please check this if you  can  ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse

Comment: hi Nazim bro fei075293@gmail.com @Nazim ch can you please contact me if you like i like to ask something regarding android . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
    private void sendEmail(File file){
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/html");
            final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
            String className = null;
            for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.google.android.gm")) {
                    className = info.activityInfo.name;

                    if(className != null && !className.isEmpty()){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", className);
            emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xyz@abc.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            startActivity(emailIntent);

        }
```

Comment: where should I add parse email id column name here ?  @Mehul Kabaria

Comment: my parse column name  for get emails is "email" .. where can i add it here

Comment: hi @Mehul Kabaria please check this if you can .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse